# ATmega8 Timer2 problem

Tags: avr

I am using ATmega8 with 16 MHz clock and use Timer2 as PWM with this code:

```
DDRB |= (1 << DDB3);
OCR2 = 0;
TCCR2 |= (1 << COM21);
TCCR2 |= (1 << WGM21) | (1 << WGM20);
TCCR2 |= (1 << CS21);
OCR2 = 0;
```

But after this code 0 PWM my led was start with low brightness. So please give me solution.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the datasheet yet?

Comment: What does the output look like on a scope?

Comment: I'm going to guess that it looks like a 7812.5Hz PWM signal.

Answer (score 1):

Since you set your prescaler to 8 and use Fast PWM mode, your PWM frequency is about 7812kHz (16MHz / (8 * 256)) as Ignacio already pointed out. If you want see your LED blinking you probably have to lower the frequency.

However, I suspect the main problem is, that you set OCR2 to 0. The resulting duty cycle depends on the OCR2 value.

> The extreme values for the OCR2 Register represent special cases when generating a PWM
>   waveform output in the fast PWM mode. **If the OCR2 is set equal to BOTTOM, the output will be
>   a narrow spike for each MAX+1 timer clock cycle**.

Comment: Then what should i do, for gat exact PWM at timer2.

Comment: @Ramoliya.Biren: How do you define EXACT PWM? What do you want to achieve? 50% duty cycle? What frequency?

Comment: No i wont to make RGB led controller devise fro that i wont variable duty cycle. and i don't know about frequency that i want.